# Why [[likely]] attribute in C++20 raises a warning here?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    if(a < b) [[likely]] {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(3,1) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a56e638e402a74e)

According to the reference, it seems like this is how we're supposed to decorate `if` clauses with `[[likely]]` or `[[unlikely]]` attributes. It's also supported in C++20 (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely)).

However, I'm running into a warning:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int foo(int, int)':
main.cpp:5:15: warning: attributes at the beginning of statement are ignored [-Wattributes]
    5 |     if(a < b) [[likely]] {
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The codebase is strict about warnings, and this will cause builds to fail. So, am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

g++ version on my macbook:

```
g++-9 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: "*According to the reference*" - *which* reference are you referring to?

Comment: There are a few. Here is one of them: https://usingstdcpp.org/2018/03/18/jacksonville18-iso-cpp-report/

Comment: Seems like gcc used to accept only before the `if`, and now accepts both versions. Maybe you should add `language-lawyer` tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. This is due to GCC's implementer [overlooking the fact that attributes on compound-statements are a thing](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2019-September/530189.html).

`[[likely]] if (whatever) {}` means something else entirely - it means that the `if` statement itself is "likely", not a branch of it.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll just wait until the fix is shipped before incorporating it. Perhaps clang has a working impl :P